# Firebase Cloud Messaging unsupported in Chrome on Windows and Mac

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase in angular 2+ and got this error in Google Chrome on Windows and MacOS as well. It's working fine on browsers on Ubuntu and Mozilla Firefox on Windows and Mac.

firebase version-> 5.5.3
angular version -> 6

Does anyone is having the idea regarding the same. please refer this link for the exact error

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the error as text instead of adding it as a screenshot. Makes it easier to read and research. :-)

Comment: Could you specify your `@angular/fire` version?

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling all Chrome extensions and using SSL/https.

See this Github [thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1220#issuecomment-421317994) for more information.